# Is there a way to execute javascript in QDomDocument?

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

In QWebView i can execute javascript code.
But QWebView isn't for running in threads and i'd like to move the execution to threads.

Is there a way of executing a javascript inside a QDomDocument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to execute Javascript code in a thread different from the UI thread you might want to have a look at the [WorkerScript QML element](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qml-workerscript.html) and [this document](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qdeclarativejavascript.html) which explains the relationship between Javascript and QML. I've never tried but it should be a correct way of doing what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

QDomDocument has nothing to do with Javascript, it's only used for manipulating XML documents.  You probably want to look at QScriptEngine.